# How to convert datetime following format?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, jquery-jtable

I am working with sailsjs(node.js), I have get all the data from mysql database and display the data in jtable but date format is coming like this:
`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z`.

I need to convert this(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z) format into `14-08-2015 04:36:04 PM

In jtable i have used following format but not working.

```
UpdatedDate: {
  edit: false,
  create: false,
  type: 'datewithtime',
  displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  Weightage: 2,
  tooltip: 'Date Modified',
  title: 'Date Modified'
  /*display: function (data) {
   return moment(data).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
   // return data.format("dd-m-yy");
   }*/
}

in model 
  CreatedDate : { type: 'DATETIME'},
```

Comment: use http://momentjs.com/ its pretty cool to deal with dates.

Comment: I have tried but not working, Its show today date. see this code    return moment(data).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

Comment: see my jtable code   UpdatedDate: {
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    type: 'datewithtime',
                    displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    Weightage: 2,
                    tooltip: 'Date Modified',
                    title: 'Date Modified'
                    /*display: function (data) {
                       return moment(data).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
                     // return data.format("dd-m-yy");
                    }*/
                },

Comment: You mean you want to save in that format ? Well mysql datetime or timestamp does not support that format it needs to be in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format, however at the time of display you can format the way you want.

Comment: If you are using model for add/edit and view I would suggest to have a model for display and you can format the date

Comment: I am working Existing database, I have only read data from database and display in jtable that following format. I need to change

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(data)` and see what value is coming ?

Comment: CreatedDate: '2015-03-31T08:10:15.000Z', in console print.

Comment: `return data.format("dd-m-yy");` does not look correct check the moment doc for format parameters for display pattern `14-08-2015 04:36:04 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple workaround using just javascript. This may not be the best way to do this but its simple and works.

```
var date = new Date("1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00");//this is the format you have
date.toLocaleDateString().split('/').join('-')+" "+date.toLocaleTimeString() //this converts it to necessary format
OUTPUT: "11-5-1994 6:45:30 PM"
```

EDIT: Sorry for that I guess it converted date as per your System Locale. Ok well so raw fix is as follows ::

```
var date = new Date("1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00");//this is the format you have")
var datePart = date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getFullYear();
function formatAMPM(date) { 

var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes +':'+secs+ ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}
var timePart = formatAMPM(date);
console.log(datePart+" "+timePart);
```

OK this time each field was extracted individually rather than using any existing format so this will work for sure. Alternatively if you are open to using external libraries here is another solution using moment.js

```
moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss A")
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried but I got like this (Tue Mar 31 2015 11:10:15 GMT+0300 (Arab Standard Time)

Comment: @kather I have edited my response. The solution now should work. Remember when calling moment(date).format(); the date should contain a date object if you don't pass it you will get present date.

Comment: thanks for your effort. I will try this logic. but Month is coming wrong that is input is 16.10.15  and  output  for your code is  16.9.15. can you please resolve this issue ?

Comment: Issue in this line. please help me.
var datePart = date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getFullYear();

Comment: Incorrect month and hours can you please resolve this issue.  I have give  input  "1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00" but output is " 5-10-1994 4:15:30 PM"  see month and hours..its different.

Comment: Sorry Its working fine. I have add like  date.getDate() +1 .

Comment: @kather sorry I dint notice that myself. getMonth() returns month in range 0-11 (starts from month 0),similarly for getDate() but you figured that out yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

Make following changes when selecting data from table:

> displayFormat: '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p'

Comment: I am using sailsjs.  `model.find().exec(function(err, data))`